# iOS camera access through browser. Overlay?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, ipad, ios-camera

I am developing a simple web page that will be accessed by an iOS user. It will ask them to take an upload an image.

Is there any way of controlling an overlay on top of the active camera view?

I haven't been able to find any examples of this so I assume that the browser does not have access to the live camera feed?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please let us know if any of the answers are helpful by upvoting. This will encourage others to help you in the future. If the answers do not work for you feel free to update the question for clarity or comment on the answers provided.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only do something like this inside an actual app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put an overlay on top of an active camera view. Check out the Photo Picker [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple. Inside of the delegate methods for the UIImagePickerController you can capture the image and hand it off to your code to perform the actual upload.

No, you cannot load a camera view through the browser. See the sample project for how to load the camera using the default view. How to add an overlay and how to use the image.

BTW - You may want to make use of a UIWebView to display web-based content within your app.